# current line number in Lua

Tags: lua

Does Lua support something like C's `__LINE__` macro, which returns the number of the current code line?  I know Lua has a special built-in variable called `_G`, but I don't see line number in there...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From Lua using debug.getinfo, e.g.,

```
local line = debug.getinfo(1).currentline
```

From C using lua_getinfo (This will return the linenumber inside lua code)

```
  lua_Debug ar;
  lua_getstack(L, 1, &ar);
  lua_getinfo(L, "nSl", &ar);
  int line = ar.currentline
```

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_getinfo

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.getinfo

Comment: Would the above work like this?:

io.write("Error on line" .. line)

Comment: Does this work on Lua 5.3. I was getting access violation errors in Windows. Also does work for cases when executing script as a file and in a variable (dofile and doscript calls)?

Comment: @TrustyCoder I had same problem. This only works inside a C implementation of a lua function. It does NOT work after a pcall trying to see what went wrong, I got exceptions too. (So I made my function error-handlers include this info in their error string).