# Finding a line that was called

Tags: lua

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [current line number in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555856/current-line-number-in-lua)

Is it possible, for say, to find the line that called a specified function?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have been answered here: [current line number in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555856/current-line-number-in-lua)

Answer (score 0):

Not Lua specific, but if you know what function it is, you can place a debug message before it gets called.

There may be some kind of debugging that's Lua specific that I'm unaware of.

sample

before:

```
myFunc(param1);
myFunc(param2);
myFunc(param3);
```

after:

```
io.write("About to call myFunc the first time");
myFunc(param1);
io.write("About to call myFunc the second time");
myFunc(param2);
io.write("About to call myFunc the third time");
myFunc(param3);
```

Obviously you can use more meaningful debug messages than that.

Comment: Lua isn't an acronym, btw.

And, what do you mean?

Comment: @John I wasn't ware of that, thanks! And I'll try to come up with a code example... I thought it was fairly self explanatory :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try `print(debug.traceback())`, this will give you the stack to where you call it. From there you could find the function that called you and what line it was.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to use the debug library's getinfo, using the level `2`:

```
line_of_caller = debug.getinfo(2,"l").currentline
```