# Is there a Lua Warning instead of Lua Error?

Tags: error-handling, lua, warnings

Lua has the **luaL_error**, and **lua_error** functions to be used inside a C function, like:

```
luaL_error( L, "something bad" );
```

This will cause that a error message was show and Lua execution halted. The error message will contain the line and file where it occurs:

```
Error: ../example/ex01.lua:6: something bad
```

Is there a similar function that shows the error but don't break the lua execution? but showing the line where it occurs.

Comment: You could build it yourself, using `print` and either of these methods: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2555881/1633117

Comment: Wouldn't that just be... printing a message? Or are you talking about the specific format of the message?

Comment: @NicolBolas, the OP wants line numbers, etc, in a format consistent with the one used for errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy the source code of [luaL_error](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lauxlib.c.html#luaL_error) and replace the call to `lua_error` at the end by a suitable call to `printf` using the string `lua_tostring(L,-1)`. Something like this:

```
LUALIB_API int luaL_warn (lua_State *L, const char *fmt, ...) {
  va_list argp;
  va_start(argp, fmt);
  luaL_where(L, 1);
  lua_pushvfstring(L, fmt, argp);
  va_end(argp);
  lua_concat(L, 2);
  printf("warning: %s\n",lua_tostring(L,-1));
  return 0;
}

static int luaB_warn (lua_State *L) {
      return luaL_warn(L, "%s", luaL_checkstring(L, 1));
}
```

Don't forget to export it to Lua by adding an entry in say `base_funcs` in `lbaselib.c` or by calling `lua_register(L,"warn",luaB_warn)`.

Comment: I'll test it. I'm using luajit, so i didn't found it on the source.